# geom_text with dodged barplot AND fill a missing category

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Using `mtcars`, I am creating a bar graph for `cyl` and fill `gear`. There is no car with **cyl==8 & gear==4**. When plotted, I used `position_dodge(preserve = "single")` to preserve the width of bars. Then, using `geom_text` I am adding labels to bars.

```
library(ggplot)
library(dplyr)

df <- count(mtcars, cyl, gear)

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = n, fill = factor(gear))) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = n, y = n + .07), size = 5, vjust = 0, 
                position = position_dodge(width=.9))
```

Two problems come out:

1. The text labels are off for the last group, that is **cyl==8**
2. In the last group, there should be a gap between red and blue bars for the green color bar. Instead you see red and blue bars are side by side.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is where `complete` from `tidyr` can help by filling in those missing values.  You also can use `vjust` entirely rather than adding to your y values, if you wish.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- count(mtcars, cyl, gear) %>% 
  complete(cyl, gear, fill = list(n = 0))

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = n, fill = factor(gear))) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = n, y = n), size = 5, vjust = -0.5, 
            position = position_dodge(width=.9))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>