# How to use position_dodge with preserve = 'single' in geom_text?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to label the bars with geom_text. It works in most cases with position_dodge, but for some cases I get plots that look like this. I use `preserve = 'single'` to get around the wide bars, but the respective `geom_text` does not move to match the bar. I've made it work with `position_dodge2()` but I like how the bars are aligned in `position_dodge` all the way to the left in this case.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), fill = factor(vs))) + 
    geom_bar(aes(y = ..count..), stat = 'count', position = position_dodge(preserve = 'single')) + 
    geom_text(aes(label = ..count..), stat = 'count', position = position_dodge(width = 1))
```

[image]

The "14" on factor 8 is aligned to the middle instead of to the left. Is there a simple fix to this?

If I switch to `position_dodge2` and use `preserve = 'single'` it works, but the bar is centered on the x axis. In `position_dodge` the bar is left aligned and the missing value is right aligned. If there is a way to use `position_dodge2` without sacrificing alignment that would work as well.

[image]

Comment: If you switch to `position_dodge2` annd add `preserve = 'single'` to the text, does that get what you want? If not, the workarounds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54242341/5325862) should help

Comment: Those are good workarounds. I'm trying to find a way to keep the alignment that `position_dodge` results in. I tried using what you suggested (please see edit).

Answer (score 3):

I don't love this, but one possibility is to enumerate the possibilities with `tidyr::complete` so that any missing ones get an NA, which will plot with the spacing you want:

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>%
  count(cyl = factor(cyl), vs = factor(vs)) %>%
  complete(cyl, vs) %>%   # creates "8 cyl / 1 vs / NA n" row
  ggplot(aes(cyl, n, fill = vs)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(preserve = 'single')) +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), position = position_dodge(width = 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You could do it manually like this:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, fill = factor(vs))) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..count..), stat = 'count', position = position_dodge(preserve = 'single')) + 
    # geom_text(aes(label = ..count..), stat = 'count', position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  geom_text(aes(x=5.5, label="4.5", y=4), colour="#376795", text=element_text(size=11)) +
  geom_text(aes(x=6.5, label="4", y=5), colour="#376795", text=element_text(size=11)) +
  geom_text(aes(x=3.5, label="1", y=3), colour="#376795", text=element_text(size=11)) +
  geom_text(aes(x=4.5, label="10", y=11), colour="#376795", text=element_text(size=11)) +
  geom_text(aes(x=7.5, label="14", y=15), colour="#376795", text=element_text(size=11))
```

But you would have to leave the cyl as a double. This is not like an efficient method that is generalizable but it gets the job done for this ask.

[image]

Comment: Hardcoding data like this is a pretty bad idea, not least of which because any typos you make in your code then become labels that mislead your viewers. In fact, you have one with the 4.5 label. It also just goes counter to the whole design scheme of ggplot. You'd also have to come up with some way of consistently placing the labels, since right now they aren't all at the same height above their respective bars

Comment: I agree with what you are saying. It was my best attempt but I can see it's not the best answer here. Specifically, I didn't know about preserve = 'single'